# How to check (in template) if $user->can('access', $request) in CakePHP 4?

Tags: php, authorization, cakephp-4.x

I've created a RequestPolicy in **src/Policy/RequestPolicy.php** to allow access to all actions of my SuperRubriquesController only to a "super-admin" user :

```
namespace App\Policy;

use Authorization\Policy\RequestPolicyInterface;
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;
use Authorization\IdentityInterface;

class RequestPolicy implements RequestPolicyInterface
{
    /**
     * Method to check if the request can be accessed
     *
     * @param \Authorization\IdentityInterface|null $identity Identity
     * @param \Cake\Http\ServerRequest $request Server Request
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canAccess($identity, ServerRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->getParam('controller') === 'SuperRubriques' && $identity) {
            return $identity->role === 'super-admin';
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

It works fine when I go to "/super-rubriques/index" or others actions of SuperRubriquesController but I'm wondering if there's a way to check if a user can access to a request from a template.
For example, I'd like to check if user can access to action index of SuperRubriquesController before to display the link.

```
if ($this->request->getAttribute('identity')->can('access', $requestToSuperRubriquesIndex)) {
    echo $this->Html->link('Super Rubriques', ['controller' => 'SuperRubriques', 'action' => 'index']);
}
```

How can I build `$requestToSuperRubriquesIndex` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the `with*` methods of the current request object to create a clone with modified data:

```php
$requestToSuperRubriquesIndex = $this->request
    ->withParam('controller', 'SuperRubriques')
    ->withParam('action', 'index');
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Http\ServerRequest::withParam()](https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/class-Cake.Http.ServerRequest.html#withParam())**

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. Concerning "ps", checking `$identity` inside of the controller condition would throw a forbidden exception when user is not authenticated instead of redirect him to login page.

Comment: @Oliv So I guess you're using the request authorization middleware?

Comment: You mean authentication middleware ? Yes I am. So is Requestpolicy::canAccess() code seems ok (i.e secured) for you ?

Comment: @Oliv No, I mean `RequestAuthorizationMiddleware`, this one would check authorization before the authentication component checks in the controller, which usually cause the redirect. In case of that middleware the check would be OK, as the identity being `null` and the authentication checks happening later on would be expected.

Comment: Yes I'm using `AuthenticationMiddleware`, `AuthorizationMiddleware` and `RequestAuthorizationMiddleware` in that order in Application::middleware(). Thank you